# class template, allocator_traits

Tags: c++, templates, stl

```
using namespace std::rel_ops;

template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class my_vector {
    public:
        typedef A                                        allocator_type;
        typedef typename allocator_type::value_type      value_type;

        typedef typename allocator_type::size_type       size_type;
        typedef typename allocator_type::difference_type difference_type;

        typedef typename allocator_type::pointer         pointer;
        typedef typename allocator_type::const_pointer   const_pointer;

        typedef typename allocator_type::reference       reference;
        typedef typename allocator_type::const_reference const_reference;

        typedef typename allocator_type::pointer         iterator;
        typedef typename allocator_type::const_pointer   const_iterator;

    public:
        friend bool operator == (const my_vector& lhs, const my_vector& rhs) {
            return (lhs.size() == rhs.size()) && std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());}

        friend bool operator < (const my_vector& lhs, const my_vector& rhs) {
            return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());}

        friend void swap (my_vector& x, my_vector& y) {
            x.swap(y);}

    private:
        allocator_type _a;

        pointer _b;
        pointer _e; // size
        pointer _l; // capacity

    private:
        bool valid () const {
            return (!_b && !_e && !_l) || ((_b <= _e) && (_e <= _l));}

        my_vector (const my_vector& that, size_type c) :
                _a (that._a) {
            assert(c >= that.size());
            _b = _a.allocate(c);
            _e = _b + that.size();
            _l = _b + c;
            my_uninitialized_copy(_a, that.begin(), that.end(), begin());
            assert(valid());}
```

I was going over this snippet of code, and there are many things that I don't understand, since I am new to C++.

1. In "`bool valid () const` ", what is this line, "`(!_b && !_e && !_l)`" trying to do?

It's negating the pointers, and I don't know what it does, and what's it's trying to accomplish.

1. In line, "`my_vector (const my_vector& that, size_type c) :`," what is the type of '`that`'? Is it a reference to its own class?
2. In "`my_vector (const my_vector& that, size_type c) :`", what is this line doing, "`_a (that._a) :`" ?  Is '`_a`' an Allocator object? because below this line, there is "`_a.allocate(c),` " and 'allocate' is a member function of Allocator.
3. What's the purpose of having both const_pointer and pointer? Also, both reference and const_reference, and both iterator and const_iterator? in the first public under the class my_vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### 1. The statement `!_x`

... (where x can be `b`, `e` or `l`.) is true if the pointer `_x` is `0`, `NULL` or `nullptr`.

It negates the value of the result of the cast from pointer to boolean. Therefore, `(!_b && !_e && !_l)` is `true` if none of the pointers is set.

> #### 2) `const my_vector& that` ...

... is a const referent to `my_vector` (which is actually the current class, so this is probably a constructor that copies the object with additional information handed in via `c`.

> #### 3) The object `_a` ...

... is declared as `allocator_type _a;`, where `allocator_type` is a typedef for `A` which is a template argument defaulted to `std::allocator<T>`.

Have a look:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
...
typedef A allocator_type;
...
allocator_type _a;
...
```

---

The expression in question (comment) is a member intialization list (with only 1 element)

```
 my_vector (const my_vector& that, size_type c) : _a (that._a) 
 {
 // ...
 }
```

It basically means "initialize `_a` with the value of `that._a`" in this case, since both have the same type, the copy constructor of `_a` is invoked.

---

The purpose of such typedefs is to enable gneric programming.

```
template<class Container>
void insert_sorted (Container & object, 
  typename Container::const_reference value)
{
  typename Container::size_type const N = object.size(), 
    find_index = find_sorted(object, value);
    if (find_index < N) 
      object.insert(object.begin()+find_index, value);
    else object.push_back(value);
}
```

The code is valid only if the Container for which it is used defines

- a type(def) `const_reference`
- a type(def) `size_type`
- a method `insert()` that takes an iterator and a `const_reference`
- a method `push_back()` that takes a `const_reference`

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one more, for 3, what does this do, "_a (that._a)"?

Comment: @Nayana There you go.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, Thank you so much. I was wondering how '_a' could take an argument when it's not a function.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, I added one more question. Could you please explain that also? Sorry for a bunch of questions. I really appreciate your help.